# @font-face Isn't Working On One Specific Font

Tags: html, css, fonts, cross-browser, font-face

I'm trying to get a site up and running for a client but I'm having issues with the fonts. All of the fonts are working properly except for one, and I'm not sure why. The problem is even worse in Internet Explorer where 2 fonts don't work, and in Edge where nothing works. This is the code I'm using. The font that isn't working is "chunkfive".

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'chunkfive';
    src: url('fonts/chunkfive-webfont-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/chunkfive-webfont-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto';
    src: url('fonts/roboto-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/roboto-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'streetwear';
    src: url('fonts/streetwear-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/streetwear-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
    font-family: streetwear, serif;
}

nav {
    background: #000;
    border: solid 4px #FFF;
    font-family: chunkfive, serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -425px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 143px;
    width: 850px;
    z-index: 0;
}

ol,
p,
ul {
    font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

The fonts all work perfectly on my free website, but when posted on an account with GoDaddy, they haven't been working properly. Using chrome, I get the following error for each font, even though the fonts other than chunkfive display correctly:

```
GET http://website-url.com/css/fonts/streetwear-webfont.woff2
```

Does GoDaddy somehow restrict the way you can use fonts, or is there something else I need to fix?

Comment: you're not showing an error. You're just showing the network request - where is the error text?

Comment: There's a big X next to this.

Comment: And that's still not an error. That's just a console log. Go to your network tab, see what the *actual* error is. Is it a 404? 403? 500? The dev tools give you a lot of information, check all of it. Especially make sure you're actually *logging* everything: by default your dev tools may not even show you all the warnings and errors for all the categories (check which options are turned on, and if not all of them are errors+warnings, set them to that)

Answer (score 0):

THere are 2-3 things you can do to make this problem go away-
 1. Check the linking is correct.
 2. Try to use double quotes instead of single.
 3. Check font folder premission as that is the main problem with go daddy.

Comment: The linking is correct, and works perfectly on my other hosting site. I'll try double quotes just to see if it makes any difference. How do you change font folder permissions?

Comment: Here is a refrence link frm go daddy to change folder premission.
https://in.godaddy.com/help/set-directory-permissions-16135